# Optimize gcc for refactoring

Tags: gcc, refactoring

I am doing a lot of refactoring.  This entails many check compiles.  When a compile encounters neither parse nor semantic errors I want to know as soon as possible.  I am not interested in waiting for code generation.

So my question is: Is there a way to tell gcc to stop and return a success status if it gets through parsing and semantics?

Comment: `-fsyntax-only` but it stops a bit too early IIRC.